# Finding Protege + owl api + pellet ignazio1977 configurations

Tags: owl, protege, owl-api, pellet

I have a set of ontologies for which I use the Pellet reasoner to reason over in Protege 5.5.0.  The reasoner completes inference over the ontologies in 20 seconds.

When I use the OWL API code implementation, it takes the Pellet reasoner 45 minutes to reason over the set of ontologies.

Where or how can I find the configuration settings used in the Protege Plugin, to compare it to the defaults for the OWL API implementation, which are currently being used?

I have tried to locate configurations in files in the installation, as well as in the source code for the Protege plu-gin, but I cannot figure out how it is configured.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I don't know what kind of configuration you mean, but the default inferences being computed are here: https://github.com/protegeproject/protege/blob/master/protege-editor-owl/src/main/java/org/protege/editor/owl/model/inference/ReasonerPreferences.java

Comment: I also don't understand what you mean by multiple ontologies - how do you open the ontologies in Protege? Each in a separate window?

Comment: Please add the owlapi code you're using.

Comment: Thank you for your responses.
In protege I open the root ontology which imports the other ontologies.
I have since looked at the code implementation (which I did not implement) and it appears the programmer basically stripped all import statements from the ontologies and imported the rest of the axioms/statements into one ontology/document.  We are busy investigating if this could cause the reasoner to slow down significantly.